# Bug with if else and markup in the view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an `if/else` block in my view which display some html based on some `ViewBag` data, but it seems I have an error in the razor syntax (I am new to razor), I get the following msg:

> Parser Error Message: The if block is missing a closing "}" character.  Make sure you have a matching "}" character for all the "{" characters within this block, and that none of the "}" characters are being interpreted as markup.

relevant code:

```
@if (ViewBag.Sidebar == "Yes")
        {
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3">
                @Html.Action("SidebarPartial", "Pages")
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">
        }
        else
        {
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
        }
            @RenderBody()
            </div>
```

Comment: Try to open and close your div in one if block. not proper closing div confusing to razor

Comment: Yes it works like that thanks!, though it wouldn't  hurt to make the original code work kind of as is if possible.

Comment: Or you can try like this  `@:<div class="classname">` with your if else div's

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do it like this

```
@if (ViewBag.Sidebar == "Yes")
{
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3">
      @Html.Action("SidebarPartial", "Pages")
   </div>
      @Html.Raw("<div class='col-xs-12 col-md-8'>")
}
else
{
      @Html.Raw("<div class='col-xs-12 col-md-12'>")
}
  @RenderBody()

 </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not a bug of razor. Not proper closing div confusing to razor.

You should open and close your div in one if block. that is one solution, other than that you can also use class like this.

```
@if (ViewBag.Sidebar == "Yes")
{
     @:<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3">           
        @Html.Action("SidebarPartial", "Pages")
       </div>

     @:<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">
 }
 else
 {
        @:<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
 }
            @RenderBody()
        </div>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You could store the class in a string:

```
@{
string cls = "col-md-12";
if (ViewBag.Sidebar == "Yes") { cls = "col-md-8"; }
}

    @if (ViewBag.Sidebar == "Yes")
    {
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3">
            @Html.Action("SidebarPartial", "Pages")
        </div>
    }

        <div class="col-xs-12 @cls">
        @RenderBody()
        </div>
```